# How do I use rpresto to connect to a database using https?

Tags: r, https, presto

When I try to connect to the database through a new port I get the following error:

```
 Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I've been provided with this Python example:

```
prestoconnector = presto.connect(host='presto.###.####.######.com', 
                                 port='###',
                                 protocol='https',
                                 username='{ad_username}',
                                 password='{ad_password}')
```

(addresses and port numbers obfuscated with # above)

I have updated everything in the corresponding places using the dbConnect function in R, but I see no place to specify that we are using the https protocol. I believe this is my problem.

I have perused the documentation for the RPresto package and DBI package, but I have not found anything helpful. Searching is challenging as there are many false positives for the search term https due to url's in the results.

```
presto <- dbConnect(
  Presto(),
  user = #####,
  password = #####,
  host = "presto.###.####.######.com",
  port = ###,
  catalog = "hive",
  schema = ""
)
```

I expect to be able to connect, but I am unable to. I am able to connect using different settings through a different port. The old port will soon be unavailable and all connections will need to be done through https at the new port. My team is the only team using R in the organization, so unfortunately, internal support has not been helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `host = "https://presto.###.####.######.com"`?

Comment: I was used rjdbc with the host to `presto.###.com&SSL=true`.

Comment: I tried appending &SSL = true to the url as @Lamanus suggested, but I get the error
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: presto.###.com&SSL=true

Comment: I have tried host = "https://presto.###.####.######.com". I get the following error: ``` Error in check.status.code(post.response) : Received error response (HTTP 401): <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/> <title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2> <p>Problem accessing /v1/statement. Reason: <pre> Unauthorized</pre></p> </body> </html> ``

Comment: I have reposted the comment above a couple times, and it keeps stripping the https prefix from the host parameter

Comment: I figured out how to do it cutting rpresto out of the loop
download driver: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/presto/presto-jdbc/0.225/presto-jdbc-0.225.jar
```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
new_presto_driver <- JDBC(classPath = "path/to/driver/referenced/above.jar"))

presto_jdbc <- dbConnect(
  new_presto_driver,
  user = "dlucas",
  password = "password",
  url = "jdbc:presto://presto.###.com:PORT_NUMBER/CATALOG",
  SSL = true
)```

If there's an error when loading rJava, you may need to enter this in terminal: sudo R CMD javareconf

Comment: @dlucas I am using R console in SageMaker looks like the connection is working but when I try to run a query. I get the below error.

Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ", : Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for use hive.default; (Error executing query)
Traceback:

1. dbSendQuery(conn, "use hive.default;")
2. dbSendQuery(conn, "use hive.default;")
3. .local(conn, statement, ...)
4. .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ", 
 .     statement)
5. stop(..., " (", .jcall(x, "S", "getMessage"), ")")

Comment: @dlucas I get this no matter what SQL I run from the SageMaker R console to Presto running on EMR

Comment: @dlucas and here is the code

Comment: library(DBI)
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx8g" )
drv <- JDBC("com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver",
  "/tmp/presto_jar/presto-jdbc-0.227.jar",
  identifier.quote="`")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:presto://host_name:8080/hive/default?user=user_name&password=pass-word&SSL=true")
res <- dbSendQuery(conn, "use hive.default;")

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it cutting rpresto out of the loop

Download the Presto driver here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/presto/presto-jdbc/0.225/presto-jdbc-0.225.jar

Then this code will connect you to your db

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
new_presto_driver <- JDBC(classPath = "path/to/driver/referenced/above.jar"))

presto_jdbc <- dbConnect(
  new_presto_driver,
  user = "dlucas",
  password = "password",
  url = "jdbc:presto://presto.###.com:PORT_NUMBER/CATALOG",
  SSL = true
)
```

Of course, replace PORT_NUMBER and CATALOG with the relevant values for your database

If there's an error when loading rJava, you may need to enter this in terminal:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

This may need to be repeated each time you update Java

Both @Lamanus and @ebyhr provided helpful clues that got me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles with RPresto & dplyr, and for me it was caused by self signed ssl certificate. I had to disable certificate verification on client side via `ssl_verifypeer = 0L` to make it work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RPresto)
library(httr)

userpwd <- paste('username', 'password', sep=":")
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L, userpwd=userpwd ) )

db <- src_presto(
  host= "https://my-hostname.com",
  port= 443,
  catalog= "catalog"
)

resultset <- tbl(db, sql("select id, field1 from my_db.my_table limit 5"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. We have Trino https as well.

```
library(RPresto)
library(DBI)
library(httr)

user = 'Username'
password = 'Password'

userpwd <- paste(user, password, sep=":")
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L, userpwd = userpwd))

con <- dbConnect(
  RPresto::Presto(),
  use.trino.headers=TRUE,
  host='https://your_host_url',
  port=443,
  user=user,
  catalog='<catalog>',
  schema='<schema>'
)

df = dbGetQuery(con, 'your_sql_query')

dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have trino only as Presto client has been deprecated. I am using the below connection string but still getting an error.
The connection string being used is:

```
conn <- dbConnect(Presto(), 
use.trino.headers=TRUE,
catalog = "hive", 
schema = "default",
host="host_URL",
user="user",
port=8888)
```

The error in R console is:
"Error in check.status.code(post.response) :
Received error response (HTTP 400): BadRequest - Please use Trino Client, support for Presto Client has been deprecated"